# AWS lambda container not picking system dependency

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, containers

I am Building a lambda to denoise audio files. Python soundfile uses libsndfile system dependency which I am installing via apt in my DockerFile. The container is running fine locally but when I run it after deploying to lambda it says [ "errorMessage": "sndfile library not found",
"errorType": "OSError", ]. Here is my Dockerfile,

```
# Define global args
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/home/app"
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION="3.7"

# Stage 1 - bundle base image + runtime
# Grab a fresh copy of the image and install GCC if not installed ( In case of debian its already installed )
FROM python:${RUNTIME_VERSION} AS python-3.7

# Stage 2 - build function and dependencies
FROM python-3.7 AS build-image
# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies ( In case of debian they're already installed )
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    make \
    cmake \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev
# Include global args in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Copy handler function
COPY app/requirements.txt ${FUNCTION_DIR}/app/requirements.txt
# Optional – Install the function's dependencies
RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install -r ${FUNCTION_DIR}/app/requirements.txt --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Install Lambda Runtime Interface Client for Python
# RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install awslambdaric --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Stage 3 - final runtime image
# Grab a fresh copy of the Python image
FROM python-3.7
# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Install librosa system dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libsndfile1 \
    ffmpeg
# (Optional) Add Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator and use a script in the ENTRYPOINT for simpler local runs
# ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
# COPY entry.sh /
COPY app ${FUNCTION_DIR}/app
ENV NUMBA_CACHE_DIR=/tmp
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 /usr/local/bin/libsndfile.so.1
# enable below for local testing
# COPY events ${FUNCTION_DIR}/events
# COPY .env ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /entry.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.handler.lambda_handler" ]
```

Below is my lambda config

```
{
    "FunctionName": "DenoiseAudio",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:DenoiseAudio",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/lambda-s3-role",
    "CodeSize": 0,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 120,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2021-01-25T13:41:00.000+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "84ae6e6e475cad50ae5176d6176de09e95a74d0e1cfab3df7cf66a41f65e4e19",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "43c6e7c4-27a8-4c6d-8c32-c1e074d40a62",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
    "PackageType": "Image",
    "ImageConfigResponse": {}
}
```

Comment: Post your Lambda config as well.

Comment: Do you have a repo containing the entirety of your setup?

Comment: @Austin yup just open-sourced it. Here you go [denoise-audio-lambda](https://github.com/yousufdev/denoise-audio-lambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved now. It turns out that the error log was wrong. It was happening because lambda was not assigned enough memory. As soon as I assigned enough memory the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not building from one of the AWS managed [base images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html#runtimes-images-lp) which include the [runtime interface client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html#runtimes-api-client). It also looks like you are not adding it manually as well. My recommendation is to start with the Python3.7 or Python3.8 base image (both found [here](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/python)). Then add the other libraries as needed. I would also encourage you to look at the AWS SAM implementation of container image support for Lambda functions. It will make your life easier :). You can find a video demonstration of it here: https://youtu.be/3tMc5r8gLQ8?t=1390.

If you want still want to build an image from scratch, take a look at the documents that will guide you through the requirements found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html).